# Python combine two functions using gi.repository

Tags: python-2.7, notifications

I am using `gi.repository` for desktop notifications in my code, and I created 2 different functions in order to load 2 different images from my local machine and have them displayed in the desktop notification bubble, depending on what condition is met. For this purpose I wrote a simple code to show you what I need to get achieved. I would love to keep my code as clean as possible down road and was wondering if those 2 functions can be merged together and still load the images. I may be using 8 different images later in my code and having 8 same functions doesn't look nice.

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Notify", "0.7")
from gi.repository import Notify, GdkPixbuf

def sunny(arg1, arg2):
    notification = Notify.Notification.new(arg1, arg2)
    image = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file("_sunny_day.png")
    notification.set_icon_from_pixbuf(image)
    notification.set_image_from_pixbuf(image)
    notification.show()

def cloudy(arg1, arg2):
    notification = Notify.Notification.new(arg1, arg2)
    image = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file("_cloudy_day.png")
    notification.set_icon_from_pixbuf(image)
    notification.set_image_from_pixbuf(image)
    notification.show()

while 1:
    var1 = 'Something will be here, maybe URL'

    if var1 == 'Sunny':
        sunny('Arg1', 'Arg2')
    elif var1 == 'Cloudy':
        cloudy('Arg1', 'Arg2')
```

[image: An Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the only thing that differs between the two functions is the image path, just pass that in:

```
def weather(arg1, arg2, image_path):
    notification = Notify.Notification.new(arg1, arg2)
    image = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(image_path) # Here
    notification.set_icon_from_pixbuf(image)
    notification.set_image_from_pixbuf(image)
    notification.show()
```

Then use it:

```
weather(arg1, arg2, "_sunny_day.png")
weather(arg1, arg2, "_cloudy_day.png")
```

I don't know exactly what you'd want to call this function though. `weather` is just a placeholder.

Comment: I think that's it! Man you made my day. I didn't even think of that for a sec. Thanks a lot

Comment: @uzdisral No problem. As soon as you find yourself with duplicate code, look at what's different, and try making it a new parameter of the function. If you can do that in appropriate situations, you'll learn to really clean up your code.